# How to place an HINT image inside an input field?

Tags: html

TEXT HINTS are common inside a field, but does anyone know how to use an image instead text as a field hint?

Many thanks!

Comment: First give *us* a hint what language / platform / technology you are talking about :)

Comment: HTML? Java? .NET? Win32? GTK+? Flash? Silverlight? JavaFX? GWT? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it as `background-image`.